# Resize GIF and save animation?

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, picturebox, animated-gif

I'm using this code i wrote to resize my images to fit my PictureBox:

```
//Creates a new Bitmap as the size of the window
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);

//Creates a new graphics to handle the image that is coming from the stream
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)bmp);
g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

//Resizes the image from the stream to fit our windows
g.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.loading, 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);

this.Image = (Image)bmp;
```

Works perfect !

The only problam is when im trying to resize a GIF... it resizes but i lose the animation...

Any fix for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should simply set the PictureBox's `SizeMode` to `StretchImage` to make the PictureBox stretch the image for you.